# Migration issue - duplicate user account

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, migration

I've got a situation that I don't know how to resolve. I've had a Mac setup and all worked fine. I've bought an SSD drive, installed Mavericks and used the migration assistant to move all the stuff from the previous system to the SSD disk, including the user account.

The problem is, now I've got both disk on the same machine, both with the OSX and the same user account. Sometimes it feels like I don't know which user root folder I'm using (the one on the SSD or the one on the previous HDD). I'd like to keep the OSX in both as a backup option (the SSD is plugged via USB3), but I don't want to format the HDD as I've got stuff in it that I don't want move around so I though about renaming the user root folder `~/user` in the HDD to another name. Would that cause any conflict/issue?

Comment: Holy cow dude, you did a lot of work and made it all a bit confusing. My recommendation is using Carbon Copy Cloner to run a automated copy from the HDD to the SSD once a day or week or whenever and then it is bootable. However to help you more I need more information to how data is stored/back up'd in general and why you aren't using the SSD as a primary volume

Comment: Ok, I', using the SSD as primary volume, but not internally. I got it hooked through [miniSwap/U3](http://www.firmtek.com/seritek/miniswap-u3/) because its a new iMac and I didnt want to open (look fairly complicated)the iMac and void the warranty to replace the internal disk. Also, the internal HDD is a lot bigger. The data is safe. That's good. All I want to do now is be able to use the user account via command line without causing issue because I've the got the user's root folder (currently the main user) in both disks.

Comment: If I just rename the users' root folder in the HDD, would that cause any issue?

Comment: Yes it would. Your permissions, keychains, and more can be damaged and inaccessible

Comment: Ok, but I don't actually need this user account anymore. I'll just use the one in the SSD. I do want to keep the folder there though.